# average age but excluding certain records

Tags: sql, function, date, average, datediff

I am trying to find the average age of a table but some of the records have `0000` as the year.

How do I get around this as it increases the average age?

This is what I have currently and it returns 112

```
Select
    AVG(Datediff("yyyy",cast(dob_yyyy as int),getdate()))
from ppm..master_efields
```

Comment: just use the where clause to filter out the 0000 years.

Comment: Just as an aside...   Are you sure you want to use `datediff()` to calculate age?  It does integer math, meaning that, if my 50th birthday is tomorrow, `datediff` will show me as being exactly 49 years old.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the `dob_yyyy` values?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: dob_YYYY looks like 1988, I am using microsoft sql server management studios and adding a where clause did not work

Answer (score 0):

Filter out "ancient" birth dates:

```
Select
  AVG(Datediff("yyyy",cast(dob_yyyy as int),getdate()))
from ppm.master_efields
where dob_yyyy != '0000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `WHERE` condition.

```
Select AVG(Datediff("yyyy",cast(dob_yyyy as int),getdate()))
from ppm..master_efields
WHERE dob_yyyy <> '0000'
```

You can also try restricting the `dob_yyyy` to not be zero by introducing a `CASE WHEN`.

```
Select AVG(CASE WHEN dob_yyyy <> '0000' THEN Datediff("yyyy",cast(dob_yyyy as int),getdate())) from ppm..master_efields
```

Additionally, if you are trying to show the average age by some field, don't forget to GROUP BY that field.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you casting `dob_yyyy` to an integer.  You should be using dates, not integers.

If you are storing `dob_yyyy` as a string, then you should fix your application so it is stored as a date.  But, assuming that is what you are doing, I think you want:

```
Select AVG(Datediff(year, cast(dob_yyyy as date), getdate()))
from ppm..master_efields
where dob_yyyy not like '%-0000';
```

or:

```
where dob_yyyy not like '0000-%';
```

depending on the format of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use a WHERE clause to skip invalid and NULL date of birth year values.

```
Select
    AVG(Datediff("yyyy",cast(dob_yyyy as int),getdate()))
from ppm..master_efields
WHERE (dob_yyyy IS NOT NULL) AND (dob_yyyy > '1900')
```